# React useEffect vs react-redux useSelector in @redux-toolkit Race

Tags: reactjs, redux, delay, redux-toolkit, react-state-management

I lately noticed that calling `useSelector` in a `react-redux` is a bit delayed.
Now i am using `useEffect` to check if the state is a certain value. like so:

```
const user= useSelector(state=>state.user.value);
useEffect(()=>{
   if (!user){
      alert('You have to login to see this page');
      //Redirect the visitor to the login page
   }

},[]);
```

I noticed that `useEffect` runs before `useSelector` fetch the data from the state and finds the user `null` so it displayes the message and redirects the user while I have a user in the state. By the way I am also using `redux-persist` middle-ware to store the state in the `localStorage`

I tried to delay the logic inside `useEffect` like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 setTimeout(() => {
    if (!user){
       alert('You have to login to see this page');
       //Redirect the visitor to the login page
    }
 },10000);
},[]);
```

But still it does not work as it takes the same `null` `user` that it came with in the the beginning of loading the page!!

I put this code to watch the `user` change:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('At: ' + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(',')[1] + ' user is:', user);
}, [user]);
```

And this is a screen shot of the console:
[image: console log for the snippet above]

Any hints on how to bypass this problem? Or may be I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Does using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` make any difference?

Comment: Will try this too, thanks a lot. Did not know about this react hook LOL! , I am new in React

Comment: Yes the react hoook `useLayoutEffect` SOLVED the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't sure it would work to be honest ah ah

Answer (score 2):

`user` should be a dependency of the useEffect as it's used inside

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if (!user){
      alert('You have to login to see this page');
      //Redirect the visitor to the login page
   }

},[user]);
```

Then when the `user` change it will re-run your useEffect

Comment: Still the same propblem @Julien. user is `null` and after 1 second only it is not `null` therfore the visitor was already forwarded to login

Comment: See the screen shot I added lately @Julien

Comment: I think this is normal to have it `null` at the beginning with redux-persist

Comment: Can you show how do you setup redux persist please ?

Answer (score 1):

> Or may be I am doing something wrong?

Yes, if you want to redirect the user somewhere *after* finding out that they're not logged in, you need to explicitly model this state, which is something like "auth pending" or "initializing auth". You simply don't know yet wether the user is authenticated or not, since this is potentially an async operation you need to wait for. Handling this third state explicitly (with an initial state in redux that reflects that) solves your issue. The selector returning `null` or an empty object does not tell you wether it's already confirmed that they're logged out.

Comment: You seem very right @timotgl, I will do this and may definetly mark your asnwer as a solver. Thanks a lot. But this also happens while the user is logged in already and I see the state in redux devtool filled with a user. But the page that needs the user to be there do this login that I show in question !! mmm,

Answer (score -1):

As @Arkellys suggested using the react hook `useLayoutEffect` seems to wait for all hooks to complete unlike `useEffect` and problem is solved.

As of your question @Julien the way you setup redux-persist is as follows:

1. install the package like so: `npm i redux-persist`
2. Use it as middle where when configuting the store like so:

```
const totalReducer = combineReducers({
    reduser1: reducer1Reducer,
    ...etc    
})
const persistedReducer = persistReducer({
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    transforms: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
        encryptTransform({
            secretKey: process.env.REACT_APP_CRPKEY, onError: (error) => {
                console.log('Erorr in Encryption: ', error);
            }
        })
    ] : [],

}, totalReducer);
```

Then you use the `persistedReducer` as your `reducers` in the store configuration.
Here also I am using encryption only if I am in production.

All the best.